# I want to make an insert using union all which has a column getting values from a sequence

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I tried

```
INSERT INTO my_test_one (rollno,name, sirname, Dept) 
(select rollno_seq.nextval,'name1','sirname1', Dept 
   FROM my_test_one_backup 
  WHERE dept = 500      
UNION ALL
 select rollno_seq.nextval,'name1','sirname1', Dept 
   FROM my_test_one_backup 
  WHERE dept = 501 );
```

While doing this I am getting the error

Error report:

> SQL Error: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
>   02287. 00000 -  "sequence number not allowed here"

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a `UNION` but a single `SELECT` and `OR` in this case:

```
SELECT rollno_seq.nextval,'name1','sirname1', Dept 
FROM my_test_one_backup 
WHERE dept = 500 OR dept = 501
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO my_test_one 
(rollno, name, sirname, Dept)  
SELECT rollno_seq.nextval,
       name1,
       sirname1,
       dept
  FROM (select 'name1' as name1,'sirname1' as sirname1, Dept
         FROM my_test_one_backup    
        WHERE dept = 500       
       UNION ALL  
       select 'name1','sirname1', Dept     
         FROM my_test_one_backup    
        WHERE dept = 501 );
```

Edit: Better still, use an `OR` like CodeBrickie says or and `IN` statement.

```
WHERE dept IN (500, 501);
```

Edit2:

Currently you are selecting 'name1', 'sirname1' as literals so each row returned will insert the next sequence number, 'name1', 'sirname1' and whatever the value of DEPT column is.

If your table has columns called name1 and sirname1 then you'll need to remove the single quotes (and you wouldn't need the column alias either) e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO my_test_one 
(rollno, name, sirname, Dept)  
SELECT rollno_seq.nextval,
       name1,
       sirname1,
       dept
  FROM (select name1, sirname1, Dept
         FROM my_test_one_backup    
        WHERE dept = 500       
       UNION ALL  
       select name1, sirname1, Dept     
         FROM my_test_one_backup    
        WHERE dept = 501 );
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO my_test_one 
(rollno, name, sirname, Dept)  
SELECT rollno_seq.nextval,
       name1,
       sirname1,
       dept
  FROM my_test_one_backup
 WHERE dept IN (500, 501);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use the 'name1' as name1 assignment here?

Comment: I was aliasing the column to make it easier to reference in the outer SELECT.

Comment: You do realise that enclosing a string in single quotes means it is a literal in Oracle? Your query will select 'name1' for every record returned from the query. Are you trying to select the value in a column called NAME1 instead? I'll edit my answer just in case...

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a sequence in unioned selects, so you'll need to put the union in a sub-query and the sequence in the outer query:

```
INSERT INTO my_test_one (rollno,name, sirname, Dept) 
select rollno_seq.nextval, name1, sirname1, dept
  from (SELECT 'name1' as name1,'sirname1' as sirname1, Dept 
          FROM my_test_one_backup 
         WHERE dept = 500      
         UNION ALL
        SELECT 'name1','sirname1', Dept 
          FROM my_test_one_backup 
         WHERE dept = 501 );
```

You should also note that, in SQL, double quotes indicate an object name and single quotes denote a string, so `'name1'` and `'sirname1'` will be static strings, not column references.